# LEFT JOIN ManyToMany multiple parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some problems with a MYSQL Query. I'm trying to do a `LEFT JOIN` with multiple parameters.

DB Structure:

A soldier can have more than one tag, these tags are assigned to the soldier with a ManyToMany relationship

My query is used in a search function where the user is able to add some tags he/she want to look for. So far its possible to search with one tag but as soon you add more than one tag, the query will not return an result even if it should.

Query used:

```
SELECT *
FROM soldiers s LEFT JOIN
     soldier_tag st
     ON s.id = st.soldier_id
WHERE st.tag_id = 5;
```

When the user enters 2 tags, then both tags should math. The query will become this:

```
SELECT *
FROM soldiers s LEFT JOIN
     soldier_tag st
     ON s.id = st.soldier_id
WHERE st.tag_id = 5 AND st.tag_id = 7;
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What logic do you want when a user enters more than one tag?  Do you want *any* tags to match or *all* tags to match?

Comment: All tags should match, for example if user enters 2 tags, soldier should have tag1 AND tag2 to match

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use 'IN' followed by the parameter as done below, this will consider both parameters when the query is executed.

`SELECT *
FROM soldiers s LEFT JOIN
     soldier_tag st
     ON s.id = st.soldier_id
WHERE st.tag_id IN (5,7);`

Answer (score 0):

When a join condition  is related to a set of values (eg a list of tag) You should use a in clause

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM soldiers s 
 LEFT JOIN soldier_tag st ON s.id=st.soldier_id 
 WHERE st.tag_id in (  5 , 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all tags to match, I would suggest phrasing the query as something like this:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM soldiers s
WHERE s.id IN (SELECT st.soldier_id
               FROM solder_tag st
               WHERE st.tag_id IN (5, 7)  -- construct an `IN` list instead of a bunch of boolean expressions
               GROUP BY st.soldier_id
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 2        -- 2 is the number of tags
              );
```

The subquery returns the `soldier_id`s where all the tags match.  You need to put the list in `IN` and the count in the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `OR` operator in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM soldiers s 
LEFT JOIN soldier_tag st ON s.id=st.soldier_id 
WHERE st.tag_id=5 OR st.tag_id=7
```

If it's possible to have more than 2 tags in query, it's better to use `IN` operator as @scaisEdge mentioned